# ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit ReorderList with more items than fit on the page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, reorderlist

I have a ReorderList on my page and it works just great, but...

Now, I have almost 100 items that I'd like to be able to reorder and they flow off the page, even at 8pt.  When dragging, the page does not scroll as I approach the bottom (or the top) so I have to drop my item, scroll down, then drag some more.  When I drag and drop in Word, as I approach the bottom of the window, the window scrolls so I can move to where I want to drop.

*Alternately*, it would be fine with me to have the items show up in multiple columns - their width would allow *at least* 3 columns.  But none of the CSS solutions I have found which allow a `<ul>` to have multiple columns seem to work as they require multiple `<ul>s` which I don't think I can do with the ReorderList control.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a solution, but you can scroll while dragging by using the mouse wheel.

Comment: Thinking outside the box is good.  I'll test that out when I get back to a mouse with a wheel, instead of my laptop touchpad. :)  But, then, that's not going to help any other laptop users.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea: Check if the left mouse button is being hold down, and also check for the position of the pointer on the page. If the coordinates are down at the bottom of the page at a position that you think is down enough for the page to be scrolled, then you could use the `window.scrollBy()` Method, and stop it when the Mouse button is released. You could also set a bool value when a Reorder item is clicked and while the button is down, and set it to false when it is released, and again the same idea, check for the position of the pointer.

[Sample window.scrollBy()](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html)

Good luck!

Comment: This sounds good, but when the drag operation is happening, the page doesn't seem to be listening for other mouse events.  I'm going to keep experimenting along these lines, though, thanks!